# How can I authenticate a user who belongs to another database through my other microservice in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, microservices, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm new to django and I am required to create two microservices with separate databases;

One to hold user information and the other to hold todo/tasks information. So far, I have created two separate projects with two separate databases,

1. To authenticate the user using simplejwt authentication. (todo_auth project with todo_auth database)
2. To show the todo/task information specific to that user. (todo project with todo database)

I need the todo project to verify the token by routing it back to the todo_auth project, and then I need the todo_auth project to send a response to the todo project. (By specifying the port)

How can I achieve this? Many thanks.

PS: I'm running the two django projects on the same server with different port numbers.

Comment: I think you need to focus on a single question here, its hard to tell exactly what part you need help with?  How to make the request using `requests`?  How to verify a JWT token?  How to pass a token through, etc.  I did my best to answer, but its not clear what your specific question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple JWT [provides a `verify` route](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) that you can pass a token to which will validate it was singed by the server and it is not expired.

From the documentation:

> You can also include a route for Simple JWT’s TokenVerifyView if you wish to allow API users to verify HMAC-signed tokens without having access to your signing key:
>
> ```
> from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenVerifyView
>
> urlpatterns = [
>    ...
>    path('api/token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
>    ...
> ]
> ```

If you want to do some other logic you should just write a normal view, use the JWT auth provided, and have the other one forward the token in the request

```
# todo-project
class ToDoView(APIView):
   def get(self, request):
       auth = request.headers["authorization"]
       response = requests.get(
           "http://todo-auth.sevice.com/api/do-thing/", 
           headers={
               "Authorization": auth
           }
       )
       if response.status_code = 200: 
           do_something(response.json())

# todo-auth-service 
class DoThing(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    def get(self, request):
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I'm really glad. The logic part does seem to be what I require! How can I place this logic inside my todo-project DRF authentication class?

Comment: To add more context, I'm planning on using remote user authentication in the todo project, hence, as per my understanding once I have logged in using the todo_auth project and when I want to list data in my todo_project - by passing the token; remote user authentication would be creating a new user in the user table of the todo_project - if the user does not exist. Please let me know if the question is too deep, I'll create another question if so. Thank you very much.

Comment: I really can't follow what you are saying there.  I don't understand what it is that you are having trouble with - the code is just out of the box django + simple jwt, and standard authentication that comes with the framework.  It should work that way if you set it up following the getting started guide.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Maybe my question is not clear enough. I'll post it as another question with what I'm trying to achieve. I'll mark this answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @JohnAnderson, and I'm sorry I can't give a better answer right now.  I hope I see the next one.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73813647/10590820
This will work. You only have to use middleware to check and verify the token in another service. Or you can make an API in your first service to identify the token accordingly.